# Video to ASCII converter -- Optimization

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I've written a Python program that takes an input file, and outputs a file with each frame having been replaced by an ASCII art rendering of it. It works fine, except that it is very, very slow. What is taking all the time is the `draw.multiline_text` function call (On my machine it averages ~12 seconds per frame). It makes sense since I'm writing a 1920 * 1080 long string onto an image. Previously I instead had 1080 strings of length 1920, and used the `draw.text` function inside a loop instead, but this too was very slow.

I'm not at all experienced with ImageDraw, so if anyone sees something that I'm obviously doing wrong here I'd appreciate input.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import timeit

SCALING    = 1.0
YSTRETCH   = 0.5
FONTSIZE   = 8

font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/UbuntuMono-R.ttf",
                            FONTSIZE, encoding="unic")
chars = list("$@B%8&M#*ahkbdqwmZO0QLCJUYXzcvnxrjft/\|()1{}[]?-_+~<>i!lI:,^`'. ")
vidcap = cv.VideoCapture('big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4')

# Read first frame to determine scaling.
success,frame    = vidcap.read()
height, width, _ = frame.shape
height           = int(height * SCALING * YSTRETCH)
width            = int(width * SCALING)

# Find total length of video.
property_id = int(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) 
num_frames  = int(cv.VideoCapture.get(vidcap, property_id))

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv.VideoWriter('outvid.mp4', fourcc, 24.0, (width * 4, height * 8))

# Capture and convert each frame of video.
count = 0
while success:
    # Resize frame.
    frame = cv.resize(frame, (width, height), interpolation = cv.INTER_AREA)

    # Convert to grayscale and reduce image depth to 64 bits per pixel.
    b, g, r = cv.split(frame)
    frame = np.maximum(b, g, r)
    frame = frame // 4

    # Create a 2D array of characters representing each pixel's brightness.
    out_mat = [[0 for x in range(width+1)] for y in range(height)]
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            brightness = frame[i][j]
            out_mat[i][j] = chars[brightness]
        out_mat[i][width] = '\n'


    # Create output frame.
    out_frame = Image.new("RGB", (width * 4, height * 8), (255, 255, 255))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(out_frame)

    # Draw ASCII to the frame.
    frame_text = ''.join([j for sub in out_mat for j in sub])
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    draw.multiline_text((0, 0), frame_text, font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
    print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

    # Save output image.
    out_frame = np.array(out_frame)
    out.write(out_frame)
    count += 1

    # Read next frame.
    success, frame = vidcap.read()

    # Report status to user.
    print("%.2f%%" % (count / num_frames * 100))

out.release()
```

Comment: Maybe you could render the characters on your output image using OpenCV's [cv2.putText](https://pythonexamples.org/python-opencv-write-text-on-image-puttext/) directly inside the loop where you traverse the image, omitting the call to `draw.multiline_text` altogether. Now, that way of traversing the image is also slow. Generally, looping through an image pixel per pixel is very costly in `Python`. Vectorization is the way to go, sadly, I'm still not that versed in `NumPy` to tell you how to vectorize that operation, but maybe you could look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself trying to solve this exact problem a while back. I ended up using the `pillow` library to create font bitmaps as `numpy` arrays. From there I used the brightness value from the image to decide which font bitmap to put in the image at each location. With the help of the `reshape` and `transpose` functions, I got to a point where the whole process was completely vectorized. I'll include the links to the project source and a video explaining the algorithm as well.

Source: https://github.com/AlexEidt/ASCII-Video

Webcam Demo: https://github.com/AlexEidt/ASCII-Vision

Video explaining the algorithm: https://youtu.be/SzqKClkCi_0